# Parsing XML in Node through node-xml2js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

So I have a XML file containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<_id>4699066</_id>
<name>Houston</name>
<country>US</country>
<coord>
    <lon>-95.363274</lon>
    <lat>29.763281</lat>
</coord>
```

And the following JS

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/HoustonUS.xml', function(err, data){
  parser.parseString(data, function(err,result){
    console.log(result);
  });
  });
```

I am using these technologies in GitHub Electron and every time I run the app the console prints 'undefined' for where the result should be printed.How will I be able to print every element in the XML for the sake of debugging purposes and assign each XML element to its own variable?

Comment: Try printing err. Your XML is invalid. Valid XML has a root element which your sample is missing.

Comment: I added a root element and now the output is working fine. but how will I be able to assign parts of result like <name> or <country> as their own variable?

Comment: Don't really know.I tend to use node-xml and write my own SAX handler. It sounds like xml2js returns JSON so you should be able to parse that and extract members like `var longitude = root.coord.lon`